# Vulkan Blinking/flickering object because of compute shader

Tags: c++, synchronization, glsl, vulkan

I'm trying to render grass using compute shader evaluations (wind, recovery and gravity). So I implemented indirect rendering and decided to store a separate compute command buffer. This is how I record compute buffer:

```
void record_compute_command_buffer() {
    vk::CommandBufferBeginInfo begin_info{};
    begin_info.flags = vk::CommandBufferUsageFlagBits::eSimultaneousUse;

    GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.begin(begin_info);



GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.bindPipeline(vk::PipelineBindPoint::eCompute, GPU_.compute_pipeline_);
blade_compute_push_data push{
    camera_.get_view(),
    glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.0f), GPU_.aspect_ratio(), 0.1f, 10.0f),
    time_.delta_time,
    time_.total_time
};

push.projection_matrix[1][1] *= -1;

GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.pushConstants(GPU_.compute_pipeline_layout_, vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eCompute, 0, sizeof(push), &push);

GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.bindDescriptorSets(
    vk::PipelineBindPoint::eCompute, 
    GPU_.compute_pipeline_layout_, 
    0, 
    1, 
    &GPU_.compute_descriptor_sets_[0], 
    0, 
    nullptr
);

const int workgroup_size = 32;
const int groupcount = ((blades.size()) / workgroup_size) + 1;
GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.dispatch(groupcount, 1, 1);

GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.end();
}
```

If I create 31 blades it all goes fine. But if the blades' size is more than 31 it all results in this (video): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pYByX6qWQUiRbvDldOgTJH6scrwM5J1S

And I get no validation layer errors.

My compute shader:

```
#version 450
layout(local_size_x = 32) in;

layout(push_constant) uniform push_data {
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
    float delta_time;
    float total_time;
} push;

struct blade_t {
    vec4 v0;
    vec4 v1;
    vec4 v2;
    vec4 up;
};

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) buffer input_blades {
    blade_t all_blades[];
};

layout(set = 0, binding = 1) buffer culled_blades {
    blade_t result[];
};

layout(set = 0, binding = 2) buffer indirect_draw_params {
    uint vertex_count;   // keeps updating
    uint instance_count; // 1
    uint first_vertex;   // 0
    uint first_instance; // 0
} indirect_params;

void main() {
    uint id = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    
    if (id > indirect_params.vertex_count) return;

    if (id == 0) indirect_params.vertex_count = 0;

    barrier();

    blade_t cur_blade = all_blades[id];
    
    result[atomicAdd(indirect_params.vertex_count, 1)] = cur_blade; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (id >= all_blades.length()) return` statement solved the problem. Modified `main` function in compute shader:

```
void main() {

    uint id = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    
    if (id == 0) indirect_params.vertex_count = 0;

    if (id >= all_blades.length()) return;

    blade_t cur_blade = all_blades[id];
    
    uint index = atomicAdd(indirect_params.vertex_count, 1);
    
    if (index < result.length()) {
        result[index] = cur_blade;
    }
}
```